# Custom error handling in Go

Tags: error-handling, go

I've been reading [this blog post](http://blog.golang.org/2011/07/error-handling-and-go.html) but I'm still not convinced I know exactly what to do to get custom errors that I can return from my functions and handle outside of them.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
func doSomething() int {
    x := 0
    // Do something with x.
    ...
    if somethingBadHappened {
        return -1
    }
    if somethingElseBadHappened {
        return -2
    }
    return x
}
```

This is what I'd like to be doing:

```
func doSomething() int, ? {
    ...
    if somethingBadHappened {
        return ?, err
    }
    if somethingElseBadHappened {
        return ?, err2
    }
    return x, nil
}
```

But I'm not exactly sure how, and what to replace those question marks with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would turn

```
func doSomething() int, ? {
        ...
        if somethingBadHappened {
                return ?, err
        }

        if somethingElseBadHappened {
                return ?, err2
        }

        return x, nil
}
```

into

```
func doSomething() (r int, err error) {

        ...

        if somethingBadHappened {
                err  = err1 // Whatever satisfies the `error` interface
                return
        }

        if somethingElseBadHappened {
                err = err2 // dtto
                return
        }

        return x, nil
}
```

IOW, at the call site it is idiomatic* to ignore, never use or rely on, any other returned value if err != nil, so just don't care if `r` above has had been assigned some intermediate value or not.

(*) In the first approximatiom, i.e. if not stated otherwise. E.g. an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) explicitly declares it *can* return both `err == io.EOF` and valid data at the same time:

> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read. It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The next Read should return 0, EOF regardless.

Comment: Hmm. To satisfy the error interface, I merely need to create some new struct type with a string variable in it and create an Error implementation, right? Or is there some even simpler way?

Comment: @jnml - shouldn't `return x, nil` be `return r, nil`?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: It could be `return r, nil` too, but not necesarily. In the OP `x` stands for a local variable and it is meant like it here as well. In general, the last line can be either `return` or `reuturn expr1, expr2`.

Comment: @Knyght: The simple way how to create an ad hoc error value is to use the return value of [fmt.Errorf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf).

Comment: @jnml - But your function has no `x`, the plain `return`s would send back `r`, and you mentioned possible values of `r` in your explanatory text.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: It doesn't have to. `x` can come from other places than just being a local variable. It can be declared/computed somewhere in the '...' section e.g. In short, read `x` as 'whatever', it doesn't have to be the name of the return variable, alhthough it can be that as well. Also, a code schema is not always a valid, complete and compilable code ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You don't really need to return an int if you don't want to. You can do something like:

```
func doSomething() error {
  ...
  if somethingBadHappened {
      return errors.New("something bad happened")
  }
  if somethingElseBadHappened {
      return errors.New("something else bad happened")
  }
  return nil
}
```

or if you want to return ints

```
func doSomething() (int, error) {
  ...
  if somethingBadHappened {
      return -1, errors.New("something bad happened")
  }
  if somethingElseBadHappened {
      return -2, errors.New("something else bad happened")
  }
  return x, nil
}
```

be sure to `import "errors"` at the top.

If you want to test whether you got an error, you can do

```
x, err := doSomething()
if err != nil {
  log.Println(err)
}
```